# Get TableView selected row(s) values in same view

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I have a page with some segmented controls, text fields and table views. The user writes/selects what he wants and then taps on a button who passes all the values to another view (said values are used to perform a search).
This is a semplified version of the function who passes the values:

```
-(IBAction) doTheSearch {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];  
    // initialize the view who will perform the search
    NewSearchController *nsc = [[NewSearchController alloc] init];
    // set values from one text field and one segmented control
    nsc.testString = textfield.text;    
    NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",segmentedcontrol.selectedSegmentIndex];
    nsc.testCode = temp;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nsc animated:YES];
}
```

Is it possible to use the same function to get which row(s) is/are selected from the table views, as I do for the text field and segmented control's values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

From the above code you can get the indexPath

```
path.row
```

to get the exact row you have selected.

Comment: Dear John, first of all thank you for your reply. Maybe I'm lost but I tried that and I got an error (no property for tableView). Then if I try to initialize (in .h) and synthetize (in .m) a property named "tableView" I got alert messages everywhere saying "Local declaration of tableView hides instance variable".